# Explode function side by side same character

Tags: php, explode

I have an string

```
$str = 'one,,two,three,,,,,four';
```

I want to array like this(output of print_r)

```
Array ( [0] => one,two,three,four )
```

My code is

```
$str = 'one,,two,three,,,,,four';
$str_array = explode(',', $str);
print_r($str_array);
```

But not working Because multiple commas side by side.How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to removed empty element from array.

So your code should be:

```
$str = 'one,,two,three,,,,,four';
$str_array = array_filter(explode(',', $str));
print_r($str_array);
```

**Edited Code**

```
$str = 'one,,two,three,,,,,four';
$str_array = implode(',',array_filter(explode(',', $str)));
echo $str_array; // you will get one,two,three,four
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove multiple comma using `preg_replace` as

```
$str = 'one,,two,three,,,,,four';
echo $str_new = preg_replace('/,+/', ',', $str);// one,two,three,four
$str_array = explode(' ', $str_new);
print_r($str_array);//Array ( [0] => one,two,three,four )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <?php

    $string = 'one,,two,three,,,,,four';
    $new_array = array_filter(explode(',', $string));

     $final_array[] = implode(',',$new_array);


    print_r($final_array);

    ?>
    OUTPUT:  Array ( [0] => one,two,three,four )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'one,,two,three,,,,,four';
$result = array(preg_replace('@,+@', ',', $string));
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => one,two,three,four )
```